# SUMO + OpenCV + Python = simulation in time? Is it possible

Tags: python, opencv, dynamic, simulation, sumo

SUMO simulator: is it possible to add cars to the simulation dynamically? I wanna do script for counting cars from video input in OpenCV+python

Comment: and then I want to make simulation with the amount of cars counted in script

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. You can use the [TraCI interface](http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/TraCI). When using the python client you can use the add function in the vehicle domain (but you must add a route beforehand or use a route already defined in the sumo inputs). In general it looks like this:

```
traci.route.add("myRoute", ["edge1", "edge2"])
traci.vehicle.add("myVehicle", "myRoute")
```

See also http://www.sumo.dlr.de/daily/pydoc/traci._vehicle.html#VehicleDomain-add